# Eigenvalues and eigenspaces with isomorphisms

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, group-isomorphism

I have the following question about eigenvalues and eigenspaces in the case of an isomorphism. I am not sure how to prove those 2 statements. My intuition tells me it has something to do with diagonalizability.
[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Suppose that $f(v)=\lambda v$ for some non-zero vector $v$, then $g(f(v))=v=\lambda g(v)$. Hence $g(v)=\frac{1}{\lambda}v$. This is sufficient. It has nothing to do with diagonalizability.

Comment: I don't understand how this is relevant to the question, sorry. What are you proving there ?

Comment: @ThéodoreRozencwajg He's showing you how to start with an eigenvalue for $f$ and get a corresponding eigenvalue for $g$.

Comment: If $\lambda\in \Sigma_{f}$, that is, $\lambda$ is an eigenvalue, then there is an eigenvector $v$ for this eigenvalue. Hence $f(v)=\lambda v$. Then as I explained, $g(v)=\frac{1}{\lambda}v$. Also, $\lambda^{-1}=\frac{1}{\lambda}$. Hence $\lambda^{-1}$ is an eigenvalue of $g$, which you needed to show. Notice that the eigenvectors of $f$ for the eigenvalue $\lambda$ are also eigenvector for $g$ for the eigenvalue $\lambda^{-1}$. The converse is true as well.

Comment: In fact I don't see why you would accept the other answer over this one if you don't understand this, because the argument "a matrix and its inverse have the same eigenvectors" is essentially a bad way to phrase what is contained in this answer.

Comment: Right, I understand better now ! How would you go with b) though ?

Comment: This was $b)$ I didn't do $a)$.

Comment: $a)$ is easy. Any non-zero vector in the kernel of $f$ is an eigenvector for the eigenvalue zero (and conversely, any eigenvector corresponding to the eigenvalue zero belongs to this kernel). Since $f$ is an isomorphism the kernel is trivial.  Hence zero is not an eigenvalue of $f$.

Comment: But it works for a) too, no ? because the lambdas can't be equal to 0 since the inverse of the lambdas are the eigenvalues for g and 0 has no inverse, or does that not work ?

Comment: Almost, you don't know (yet) that $\lambda^{-1}$ is an eigenvalue of $g$, that's what we were proving. But we do know that $v=\lambda g(v)$ and $v\neq 0$. Hence $\lambda\neq 0$.

Answer (score -1):

Since $f$ is an isomorphism, you know it's 1-1 and onto, and since you know the inverse $g$ exists, you know none of the elements of $V$ can have zero eigenvalue, otherwise they're non-invertible.  (b) follows from (a) since all $v$ in $V$ are invertible, and a matrix and its inverse have the same eigenvectors.

Comment: What do you mean by "all $v$ in $V$ are invertible"?

Comment: This answer is far for complete nor makes much sense, the only valid point you make is that an isomorphism does not have zero as an eigenvalue, which is needed, otherwise $\lambda^{-1}$ doesn't make much sense.